# Trouble comparing NSString to NSArray object

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray

Ok, so I'm trying to check if an object from an `NSArray` equals something inputed by the User into a `UITextField`.  It should work, but for some reason it dosn't.  Here is my code:

```
    if (theAnswer.text == [correctAnswers objectAtIndex:problemNumber]) {
    NSLog(@"CORRECT");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"wrong");
}
```

The console always give wrong.
I put this log in:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@", theAnswer.text, [correctAnswers objectAtIndex:problemNumber]);
```

And I get `A A`

`wrong`
printed everytime.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't support the == operator for NSStrings.  That will do a comparison of the pointers to the NSStrings and not the contents of the string itself.

Try

```
if([theAnswer.text isEqualToString:[correctAnswers objectAtIndex:problemNumber]]) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I really appreciate both the quick response and the help it provided